# Drawing the hydrostatic paradox. Filling a object with several openings

Tags: tikz-pgf

The hydrostatic paradox, states that the height of the water in any container is independent of the shape of the container. The picture is like this.

[image: hydrostatic paradox]

I could define every corner to draw the black lines, and then use some of them to define the blue zone. But I don't think it is the correct way to do it.

So I don't have a MWE because, the approach of the answer is presumably totally different than my idea. (drawing is just as illustration)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could at least draw the black lines shape as a MWE.  That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.  My suggestion would be to draw the water as a rectangle and then clip it.

Comment: Fill the background with blue rectangle clipped with your lines

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok I will look for 'clip it'. The drawing is just an illustration, I only wanted the principe of the answer...

Comment: BTW, a refinement of the model would have to take the [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action) into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code defines the connected line paths as macros `\PathA` to `\PathE`.

The paths are combined to a closed path for filling. The height setting is achieved by using a rectangle as clip path with the desired fill height.

Finally the line paths are drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\Drawing}[1]{%    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\unit{5mm}
      \tikzset{
        x=\unit,
        y=\unit,
      }

      \def\PathA{% from right to left
        (17, 5) -- (18, 4) -- (18, 3.5)
        -- (17, 2.5) -- (17, 0) -- (0, 0) -- (0, 5)
      }
      \def\PathB{
        (1, 5) -- (1, 1)
        -- (3, 1) -- (3, 3) -- (2, 5)
      }
      \def\PathC{
        (5, 5) -- (4, 3) -- (4, 1)
        -- (6, 1) -- (8, 5)
      }
      \def\PathD{
        (9, 5) -- (11, 1)
        -- (12, 1) -- (12, 2) -- (13, 3) -- (11, 5)
      }
      \def\PathE{
        (12, 5) -- (14, 3) -- (13, 2) -- (13, 1)
        -- (16, 1) -- (16, 2.5) -- (15, 3.5) -- (15, 4) -- (16, 5)
      }
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (0, 0) rectangle (18, #1);
        \fill[blue]
          \PathA -- \PathB -- \PathC -- \PathD -- \PathE -- cycle
        ;
      \end{scope}
      \draw[very thick, line cap=round]
        \PathA
        \PathB
        \PathC
        \PathD
        \PathE
      ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \newpage
  }
  \foreach \h in {0, .25, ..., 5} {
    \Drawing\h
  }
\end{document}
```

The image of the question is available as `\Drawing{4}`. The animated version:

> [image: Animation]

A version without clipping:

Comment: Explanation off your solution made an other 'learn something LaTeX every day"-day

Comment: To avoid the line at the top for the full fill height, I have simplified the algorithm.